# How do I make a Ruby method that lasts for the lifetime of a block?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Inside the body of a class, I'd like to pass a block to a method called `with`. For the lifetime of the block, I would like a `with_value` method to be available.

Otherwise, everything inside the block should behave as if it were outside the block.

Here's an example:

```
class C
  extend M

  with "some value" do
    do_something_complicated
    do_something_complicated
    do_something_complicated
  end
end
```

We can *almost* get this with:

```
module M
  def with(str, &block)
    Object.new.tap do |wrapper|
      wrapper.define_singleton_method :with_value do  # Here's our with_value
        str                                           # method.
      end
    end.instance_eval &block
  end

  def do_something_complicated                        # Push a value onto an
    (@foo ||= []).push with_value                     # array.
  end
end
```

but there's a problem: since we're evaluating the block passed to `with` inside the context of a different object, `do_something_complicated` isn't available.

What's the right way to pull this off?

Comment: You could `wrapper.extend M` before `instance_eval`ing. Can you shed some light on your reasons for this? It may help us come up with a solid solution.

Comment: @Kyle If you `extend` on the wrapper, `do_something_complicated` will push to the wrong array (the wrapper's `@foo` instead of `C`'s `@foo`. I'm doing this to make a small DSL for containing some of the mess around ActiveRecord objects in composeable forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make `with_value` available only within the block. However, `_with_value` will be defined within or outside of the block.

```
module M
  def _with_value
    ...
  end
  def with(str, &block)
    alias with_value _with_value
    block.call
    undef with_value
  end
  ...
end
```

I cannot tell from the question whether this is a problem. If it is a problem, you need to further describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: This feels pretty ugly, but it works so I can't complain. +1.

Comment: @JohnFeminella To me, it is not ugly. It has the definition body (for `_with_value`) separated from `with`, and there is only one line each before and after the block. If this is ugly to you, there is nothing you can do better.

Comment: What I mean by "ugly" is that any failure inside the block will cause `with_value` to still be there, polluting the space for subsequent invocations. In a hypothetical more elegant solution, the language would take care of that by not making it possible to see `with_value` outside the block. But since I can't think of anything better, that's why I gave you +1!

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "any failure inside the block will cause `with_value` to still be there". Can you elaborate on that? Are you expecting errors to be raised in the block, and rescuing it somewhere?

Comment: @JohnFeminella If you expect some exception to be raised in the block just wrap it in `begin-ensure-end` clause.

Comment: Accepting this answer because I think it's the closest. Thanks, @sawa.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the idea is to use [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) to forward method calls from the dummy class to the calling class. If you also need to access instance variables, you can copy them from the calling class to your dummy class, and then back again after the block returns.

The Ruby gem [`docile`](https://github.com/ms-ati/docile) is a very simple implementation of such a system. I suggest you read the source code in that repository (don't worry, it's a very small codebase) for a good example of how DSL methods like the one in your example work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that is closer to your attempt:

```
module M
  def with(str, &block)
    dup.tap do |wrapper|
      wrapper.define_singleton_method :with_value do
        ...
      end
    end.instance_eval &block
  end
  ...
end
```

`dup` will duplicate the class from where `with` is called as a class method.